# An old live action children’s show or movie set in a jungle or forest looking set?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I don’t remember the narrative as much as I remember some flashes of the visuals. I remember seeing it as a very young kid. It was a live action children’s program or movie where there were these different types of creatures, they were actors dressed in costumes kind of like *H.R. Pufnstuf*; they weren’t puppets. The set was dressed as a jungle, and I can’t fully remember but I think there was some type of talent show or contest possibly? And a group (almost like a small family) of a certain type of creature would arrive kind of like a family arriving at a reunion one by one. This could also possibly be some company that had a line of characters doing a mashup reunion show where they all come together.

Comment: Can you give us a rough time period of when this was. Was it in the 70s? 80s? 00s? Early or late in one of those decades? Also was there any fantastical or science fictional elements in it? Or was it simply that there were these different creatures living in a jungle that otherwise had very ordinary lives?

Comment: I think it was made in the early 90’s probably. And it was a children’s program so there was i think magical effects but mainly just music and a show they were all getting together to put on i think. They lived in this place and were getting together to put on some sort of show i believe

Comment: This sounds disturbingly like the "Star Wars Holiday Special".  Please don't let it be this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you compare it to *H.R. Pufnstuf* and describe it taking place in a jungle setting, I have to suggest [*Land of the Lost*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071005/), which was produced by the same people, brothers [Sid and Marty Krofft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sid_and_Marty_Krofft).

[image: Land of the Lost characters]

The show originally ran from 1974–1976, but it remained common in syndication until into the 1990s (often shown late on Saturday mornings on CBS or NBC affiliates, after the end of the network block of cartoons).

The basics of the show, per Wikipedia:

> Land of the Lost details the adventures of the Marshall family (father Rick and his children Will and Holly), who are trapped in an alternate universe or time warp inhabited by dinosaurs, a primate-type people called Pakuni, and aggressive humanoid/lizard creatures called Sleestak. ... The episode storylines focus on the family's efforts to survive and find a way back to their own world, but the exploration of the exotic inhabitants of the Land of the Lost is also an ongoing part of the story.

As it says, the most prominently occurring creatures in the show were the Sleestak, who looked like this:

[image: Sleestak]

I'm not sure which episode you might be thinking of.  (I'm not personally a fan and haven't seen that many myself.)  But this may be the overall program you were thinking of.